# Jquery Array and Data Attributes

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

Why can't I access the .data() or .attr() in an object after I select them using Jquery?

Here is the issue, I have a group of divs with a particular class assigned to them. I wan to select all the divs  using Jquery and assign them to an array, then parse through the array and look at each's data-attributes to find certain values.

```
<div class="Divs" data-eventid="1"></div>
<div class="Divs" data-eventid="2"></div>
<div class="Divs" data-eventid="3"></div>
```

The Following Gets a List of Elements that match the selector and assign them to events.

```
var events = [];
    $('.Divs').each(function () {
        events.push($(this));
    });
```

*The Variables {n1, n2, n3} are broken out for explanation reasons*

```
$.each(events, function(idx, val){
  var n1 = events[idx];
  var n2 = n1[0];
  var n3 = n2.data();  //  **.data() is Undefined
});
```

When I try to parse though the array and says that .data() or .attr() is not supported/ undefined?

But if i do the following it works fine

```
 $('.Divs').each(function () {
   var getIdValue = $(this).attr('eventid'); // Works;
   var getIdValue2 = $(this.data('eventid'); // works; 
)};
```

Just wanted to know why the one works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/brvk9q3p/

It should be : `var n3 = $(n2).data();`

This is because, `n2` refers to the `div`. You need to use jQuery reference to get its `data()`.

Check the console, when your run the fiddle..you will get more idea.